# Munsterlander & Telomian - Rebus

Tags: rebus

Solve the following rebus:

```
  Munsterlander
  Telomian
  Whippet
  Terrier
  Foxhound
  Spaniel
  Sharpei
```

Comment: This is not a rebus I believe. A rebus uses images where you have to replace/add/remove letters to create sentences.

Comment: @ValentinGrégoire, There are plenty of rebus puzzles whose answers are phrases not sentences, and there are plenty of rebus puzzles which only have text

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it's

> [Every dog has its day](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Every+dog+has+its+day)

Because:

> They are all dog breeds

And:

> **M**unsterlander **M**onday
> **T**elomian **T**uesday
> **W**hippet **W**ednessday
> **T**errier **T**hursday
> **F**oxhound **F**riday
> **S**paniel **S**aturday
> **S**harpei **S**unday

Comment: +1 Damn, never heard of that. I was going for something like "weak dog" or "week hunt" (all the dogs are hunting dogs).

Comment: They are not all dog breeds. Terrier, foxhound, and spaniel are all dog types. </pedant>

Answer (score 5):

I think it's

> Dog days

Because

> They are all dogs

And

> The first letter of each word lines up with a day of the week

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a:

> Dog Pile

Because:

> All the things listed are dog breeds. They are listed separately on each line, indicating that they are on top of, or below one another.